# html entities get passed into database even when I use html_entity_decode

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities

```
$string = "susan&#039;s"; //string is scraped from website
$string = html_entity_decode($string);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO database SET name = "'. $string .'"';
```

When I echo out $sql, it shows correct one: `INSERT INTO database SET name="susan's"`, but when I run query it inserts `susan&#039;s` into database. When I run query manually from phpmyadmin it inserts correct one. Why do html entities get passed to database even when I remove them?

Comment: @J.Litvak - (if you see this comment) I noticed you deleted your answer. Just so you know, that that was not my downvote you received for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `ENT_QUOTES` flag constant.

As per the manual:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

> ENT_QUOTES     Will convert both double and single quotes.
>   A bitmask of one or more of the following flags, which specify how to handle quotes and which document type to use. The default is ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401.

Where `ENT_COMPAT` produces `susan&#039;s`.

So your code ends up being:

```
$string = htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

**Note:** Depending on which API is used to insert this with, you need to be made aware that escaping it without using [`stripslashes()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to it and should this be the case, may produce `susan\'s`, being another undesired result.

Use a prepared statement, should this be coming from user input if you're not already doing so.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

This will help against an SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

---

> When I echo out $sql, it shows correct one: INSERT INTO database SET name="susan's",

*Tip:* Before inserting into your database, always look at your HTML source. That will reveal exactly what it is that is going to be passed in the query. That is also considered as being a "tool".

- Echo and the (HTML) source are two different animals altogether.

Comment: @Tomm Thanks. I thought the question was rather interesting, which led me to research this.

Comment: Well worth the research in my case, I did not know about this

Comment: @Tomm Yes indeed :-)